# window.top.document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript

I have these two script tags one after the other. The first one works perfectly but the second one doesn't. What could be the problem. Thanks.

```
<script>
<!--
    window.top.document.getElementById('events').innerHTML="Events: <div style='display:inline;'>"+document.getElementById('events1').innerHTML+"</div>";

-->
</script>
<script>
<!--
    window.top.document.getElementById('bal').innerHTML=document.getElementById('newbal').innerHTML;
    
    document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML=document.getElementById('newbal').innerHTML;
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Well do you get any error messages in the browser console? It should work if the elements with those ids exist.

Comment: The elements exist. I’m not getting any errors. How can I catch the errors?

Comment: If the elements do not exist you would get an error in the browser console when accessing or overwriting `innerHTML`. So what is not working then? Generally "it does not work" is not a good description to find the error.

Comment: I don’t get anything written to the destination element innerHTML. No error message is displayed.

Comment: Mmh well then how are we supposed to help you find the error? You can use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to put the element and its contents in the browser console.